# Why doesn't my new window close in the setTimeout event?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

So I make a new window using the open method and later call a setTimeout method to close it after 5 seconds but for some reason it doesnt close. I have tried to replicate this bug in another file like this: let win = window.open(''); setTimeout(function() {win.close()}, 5000); and it works just as intended( closes after 5 seconds). But in here it doesnt and when I've put some break points it just skips it and the program ends.

```
            //Global variables
            const button = document.getElementById("btn");
            //Input-Fields
            const nameInput = document.getElementById("input-name");
            const phoneNumber = document.getElementById("input-phoneNum");
            const adress = document.getElementById("input-adress");
            //Variable
            let confWindow;

            function processInput()
            {
                //if statement checks if all fields contain something
                //or true, if not they are falsy
                if(nameInput.value && phoneNumber.value && adress.value)
                {
                    //New Window size and centering
                    let winWidth = 300;
                    let winHeight = 300;
                    let leftPosition = ((screen.width - winWidth)/2);
                    let topPosition = ((screen.height - winHeight)/2);

                    //String that contains onptions for the new Window
                    let options = "width =" + winWidth + ",height=" 
                                + winHeight + ", left =" + leftPosition
                                + ", top =" + topPosition;
                    //creates a new window
                    confWindow = window.open("confirm.htm", "Confirm Page", options);
                    confWindow.document.write("<p>Hi</p>");
                    setTimeout(function(){confWindow.close()}, 5000);
                }
                else{
                    window.alert("Please Enter Information in all fields");
                }
            }



            //Event Listeners
            if(button.addEventListener)
            {  
                button.addEventListener("click", processInput, false);
                
            }
            else if(button.attachEvent)
            {
                button.attachEvent("onclick", processInput); 
            }
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your bug. Are you able to provide a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or a link to your project with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create a new window using the `open()` method and then close it after 5 seconds using the `setTimeout()` function. However, it's not closing properly and you've tried replicating the issue in another file but it works fine there.

So, you could wrap the `setTimeout()` call in a try-catch block to see if there are any errors being thrown. This can help pinpoint where the problem might be occurring.

You can also add debugging statements (`console.log()`) to see if the code is reaching the `setTimeout()` function at all. Sometimes, the code before or after the function can cause an error that prevents it from running.

Make sure that your popup blocker isn't preventing the window from opening or closing. That could be causing the behavior you're seeing.